# Default search in Opera

Tags: google-chrome, opera, search-engines

When I am in Chrome, and I need to do a search by selecting some text in a page, I do Right Click on the selection, say 'some text', and `Seach Google for 'some text'`.

In Chrome I can change the default search engine from Google to another one (but I don't want, I like Google)...

Opera proposes me multiple search engines to search, but introduces one more step to do: (1)Search With=>(2)Google. 
[image]
[image]
Is there a way to make the *default* search engine be **really** ***default*** in Opera

(right click, "`Search with 'my default search engine' for 'some text'`") ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but I'm pretty sure this is a case of *pebkac*. :-)

Please have another look at your own screenshot. *Directly above* where you've selected the "Search with" option is the option called, simply "Search". Select text, right-click on it, and choose that option. It will do exactly what you're complaining Opera doesn't have. Choosing another default search engine *will* affect what this button does, because that button uses your default search engine. In other words, you don't *have* to do the 2-step option of selecting the engine if you're happy to use the default; the additional options are there as a convenience. If you have created custom search option, they'll show up there as well.